# javascript confirm doesnt stop submitting form

Tags: javascript, php

i am trying to do a confirm function using javascript in php which it worked only in showing the buttons but whatever you press the form will submit heres the code and the function

```
<form action='Allocated.php' method='post'  >
    <input type='submit' name='disc' value='Discontue Asset'    formnovalidate='formnovalidate' onclick='myFunction()' />
    <input type='hidden' name='alloc' value='$AllocID' />
    </td>
</form>
```

and the function

```
function myFunction() {
    var r = confirm("Press a button!");
    if (r == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated
THanks

Comment: Why not condensing all the code with this line: ``onclick="return confirm('Press a button!')"``

Comment: Thank you Ibrahim for your post i tried onsubmit, it will continue to execute normally without any prompt too.

Comment: `if (r == true) { return true; } else { return false; }` is redundant. Just do `return (r == true);`. In a more sensible language, you could even shorten it to `return r;`. Alas, JavaScript isn't a sensible language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `onclick='myFunction()'` to `onsubmit='return myFunction()'` so that the returned value from the function can be returned to the event.

Answer (score 1):

Put this function at attribute **onsubmit** (*with return keyword*, thx Scott) on **form** and change to **button**

```html
<form action="Allocated.php" method="post" onsubmit="return myFunction()">
    <input type="hidden" name="alloc" value="$AllocID" />
    <button type="submit">Discontue Asset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `onsubmit="myFunction()"` needs to be `onsubmit="return myFunction()"` and using `button` instead of `input type=submit` has no bearing on this.

Comment: Exactly, I forgot to write the `return` in `onsubmit` attribute.
The `<button type="submit" />` is because it's more semantic and intuitive, in my opinion...

Comment: I meant that the button's type has no bearing on why the code wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var r = confirm("Press a button!");
    if (r) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

or:
for booleans you must use === instead of == :

```
function myFunction() {
    var r = confirm("Press a button!");
    if (r == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

or

```
function myFunction() {
    var r = confirm("Press a button!");
    if (r === 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"for booleans you must use === instead of =="* That is not true at all. Also, your first suggestion is really the only one that makes any real sense since `if` conditions are always evaluated for `true` or `false` anyway. At any rate, none of this has to do with why the form is not being prevented from submitting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try code below, It's much simpler

Give an id to your form

```
<form action='Allocated.php' method='post' id="myform">
<input type='submit' name='disc' value='Discontue Asset'    formnovalidate='formnovalidate' onclick='myFunction()' />
<input type='hidden' name='alloc' value='$AllocID' />
</td>
```

Then write your javascript like this

```
function myFunction() {
var r = confirm("Press a button!");
if (r) {
    document.getElementById('myform').submit();
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: This is a convoluted answer that won't work anyway. With an inline event handler, the word `return` must be placed in front of the function call so that the return value from the function can be returned to the event.

Comment: @ScottMarcus ok sir.